# Change css when element/div not visible on screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, vue.js

In my vue web app, I'm trying to change the CSS class of header when one of the element goes off the screen via scrolling.

I am using [jquery-visible](https://github.com/customd/jquery-visible) to find whether the element is visible or not as I could not found any vue way to do so.

Now I have following code in HTML to change the CSS class dynamically:

```
<div class="aClass" :class="{'bClass': isElemVisible()}">
   ....
   ....
</div>
```

And in my Vue code, I have added a method as following:

```
export default {
  name: 'myElem',
  methods: {
    isElemVisible () {
      console.log($('#myDiv').visible(true))
      return $('#myDiv').visible(true)
    }
  }
}
```

The problem with this is it does not changes the value returned by `isElemVisible` dynamically, it just takes the first value when loaded and not changes even after scroll and `#myDiv` goes out of screen, How can this be done or if there is a better/vue way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `isElemVisible()` is not being executed. The method has been defined and it *is* executed the first time that Vue is determining if `bClass` should be enabled, but subsequently, particularly when scrolling, it is never executed again.

Instead of a simple method that is only executed once, I'd recommend using a boolean `data` property that you update upon scrolling with the value returned by jquery-visible.

I have put together [this CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qqvEmr) to demonstrate what I mean, but in short:

```
<div id="myDiv" class="aClass" :class="{'bClass': isElemVisible}">
</div>
```

And instead of a method use a `data` property and a scroll event listener:

```
data() {
  return {
    isElemVisible: true
  }
},

created() {
  window.addEventListener('scroll', event => {
    this.isElemVisible = $('#myDiv').visible(true)
  })
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you listen to the scroll event, like this: https://github.com/vuejs/Discussion/issues/324

Comment: Yes, function gets called on scroll via this, but this did not added the class dynamically.